# HowTo use https / ssl with Maven/Mortbay Jetty Plugin?

Tags: java, maven-2, ssl, https, jetty

I would like to use ssl / https as described in

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL

using jetty-maven-plugin, but I don't know how to configure the plugin. Any hint, example, tutorial, walkthrough ?

Also, I wonder how to carry out Step 3b of the above mentioned tutorial, where manipulation the jetty server is necessary (`java -classpath $JETTY_HOME/lib/jetty-util-6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:$JETTY_HOME/lib/jetty-6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.mortbay.jetty.security.PKCS12Import jetty.pkcs12 keystore`).

Comment: Here is the only working, clear step-by-step I have found for Jetty 9: http://juplo.de/configure-https-for-jetty-maven-plugin-9-0-x/#comment-53352

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use Maven to create a development certificate and use it when starting Jetty. First, configure the *keytool-maven-plugin* to create a development certificate:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <id>clean</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>clean</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <id>genkey</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>genkey</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
    <dname>cn=my.hostname.tld</dname><!-- put your CN here-->
    <keypass>jetty6</keypass>
    <storepass>jetty6</storepass>
    <alias>jetty6</alias>
    <keyalg>RSA</keyalg>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Change the CN as you wish. Then configure the *maven-jetty-plugin* to use the development certificate:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.10</version>
  <configuration>
    <contextPath>/context</contextPath>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <connectors>
      <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <port>8080</port>
        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
      </connector>
      <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
        <port>8443</port>
        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
        <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
        <password>jetty6</password>
        <keyPassword>jetty6</keyPassword>
      </connector>
    </connectors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Run `mvn jetty:run` and open https://localhost:8443/context.

Comment: Pascal, you *are* a bit of a marvel ... again thanx alot!

Comment: +1 Excellent answer! Would you say that those Jetty configurations can  also be used with the cargo plugin using Jetty?

Comment: @PascalThivent: Do you think you could illustrate the above with the latest versions of the `keytool-maven-plugin` and Eclipse version of the `jetty-maven-plugin`? They both have significant changes compared to the time this question was asked.

Comment: I've opened a new SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832716/how-to-setup-ssl-with-eclipses-jetty-maven-plugin. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

In case  you are get this error using Pascal's solution:-

```
Could not find goal 'genkey' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.3
```

1. Use 'generateKeyPair' as the goal. (genKey is deprecated I  believe. )
2. Add plugin version.

The plugin definition should look like :-

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>genkey</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateKeyPair</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
                <dname>cn=my.hostname.tld</dname><!-- put your CN here -->
                <keypass>jetty6</keypass>
                <storepass>jetty6</storepass>
                <alias>jetty6</alias>
                <keyalg>RSA</keyalg>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to do it using Jetty 9, note that *since jetty-9.0 it is no longer possible to configure a https connector directly in the pom.xml: you need to use jetty xml config files to do it.*[[1]](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html).

Here is an example:

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
<jetty-version>9.1.2.v20140210</jetty-version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty-version}</version>
</dependency>
...
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>genkey</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateKeyPair</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
                <dname>cn=127.0.0.1</dname><!-- put your CN here -->
                <keypass>dypBdX1NB3gXA0DXCy9nfyJ4jqUDlaydgbo9OU12g</keypass>
                <storepass>dypBdX1NB3gXA0DXCy9nfyJ4jqUDlaydgbo9OU12g</storepass>
                <alias>jetty</alias>
                <keyalg>RSA</keyalg>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jettyXml>src/main/resources/jetty.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-ssl.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**jetty-https.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Call id="httpsConnector" name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                <Arg name="sslContextFactory"><Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="sslHttpConfig"/></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.https.port" default="8443" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout">30000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

**jetty-ssl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<!-- ============================================================= -->
<!-- Configure a TLS (SSL) Context Factory                         -->
<!-- This configuration must be used in conjunction with jetty.xml -->
<!-- and either jetty-https.xml or jetty-spdy.xml (but not both)   -->
<!-- ============================================================= -->
<Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
  <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.keystore" default="target/jetty-ssl.keystore"/></Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.keystore.password" default="dypBdX1NB3gXA0DXCy9nfyJ4jqUDlaydgbo9OU12g"/></Set>
  <Set name="KeyManagerPassword"><Property name="jetty.keymanager.password" default="dypBdX1NB3gXA0DXCy9nfyJ4jqUDlaydgbo9OU12g"/></Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.truststore" default="target/jetty-ssl.keystore"/></Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.truststore.password" default="dypBdX1NB3gXA0DXCy9nfyJ4jqUDlaydgbo9OU12g"/></Set>
  <Set name="EndpointIdentificationAlgorithm"></Set>
  <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
    <Array type="String">
      <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Create a TLS specific HttpConfiguration based on the        -->
  <!-- common HttpConfiguration defined in jetty.xml               -->
  <!-- Add a SecureRequestCustomizer to extract certificate and    -->
  <!-- session information                                         -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <New id="sslHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Arg><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
    <Call name="addCustomizer">
      <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
    </Call>
  </New>

</Configure>
```

**jetty.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
 <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
 <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
 <Set name="securePort">
  <Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" />
 </Set>
 </New>
</Configure>
```

Comment: This gets really close, but I'm getting: [ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.KeyToolCommandLineBuilder was bound.
[ERROR] while locating org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.DefaultKeyTool - any ideas?

Comment: And as usual, I answer my own question.  keytool-maven-plugin -> version 1.5 instead of 1.3