# How configure jetty-maven-plugin 9 to use https?

Tags: java, maven, https, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I need to use https for jetty maven plugin.

I googled following answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795116/2674303

But looks like this answer is not suitable for jetty-maven-plugin of 9 version.

[image: http://joxi.ru/J2beM5gUEG8Km6]

idea complains about syntax

How to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok,  since jetty-9.0 it is no longer possible to configure a https connector directly in the pom.xml: you need to use jetty xml config files to do it.
I am new to exchange ,so excuse my code copy/paste.

**jetty.xml**

```
 <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
 <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
 <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
 <Set name="outputBufferSize">32768</Set>
 <Set name="requestHeaderSize">8192</Set>
 <Set name="responseHeaderSize">8192</Set>
 <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
 <Set name="sendDateHeader">false</Set>
 <Set name="headerCacheSize">512</Set>

 <!-- Uncomment to enable handling of X-Forwarded- style headers
 <Call name="addCustomizer">
 <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer"/>   
 </Arg>
 </Call>
 -->
 </New>
```

Look [here](http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#maven-config-https), for whole bunch of xml's and if it is helpful please check my answer as correct

Comment: Can you advise location where I should put the file ?

Comment: You can specify the file in the maven plugin configuration as described here: https://juplo.de/configure-https-for-jetty-maven-plugin-9-0-x/